# Display xml data in silverlight datagrid, vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I want to display an xml file data in silverlight datagrid. im using the below code but it doesnt work.Please help.

My vb.net code:

Imports System 
Imports System.Collections.Generic 
Imports System.Linq 
Imports System.Windows 
Imports System.Windows.Controls 
Imports System.Xml.Linq

Namespace SilverlightApplication1 
    Public Partial Class Page 
        Inherits UserControl 
        Public Sub New() 
            InitializeComponent() 
        End Sub

```
    Private Sub Page_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs) 
        DataGrid1.ItemsSource = GetReport() 
    End Sub 

    Public Function GetStatusReport() As List(Of Table) 
        Dim statusReport As New List(Of Table)() 

        Dim doc As XElement = XElement.Load("Data/Report.xml") 

        report = (From row In doc.Elements() _ 
            Select GetStatus(row)).ToList() 

        Return statusReport 
    End Function 

    Private Function GetReport(ByVal row As XElement) As Table
        Dim s As New Table() 
        s.JobID= row.Attribute("ID").Value 
        s.VenueName= row.Attribute("Name").Value) 
        Return s 
    End Function 
End Class
```

End Namespace

Answer (score 0):

I am so confused by this code... which is probably why it is not working.

First, when you set the ItemsSource, you call GetReport() without a parameter.  GetStatusReport() is never called, even though it does the XML lifting.  Inside of GetStatusReport, you return statusReport, which is an empty list... and you never do anything with report, which is the actual query.  Inside the query, you call GetStatus, which is not defined, though I believe it should be GetReport.

Arghhh... with all that, I would guess that you want to re-write all that code to be something like this:

```
    Private Sub Page_Loaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs) 
        DataGrid1.ItemsSource = GetStatusReport() 
    End Sub 

    Public Function GetStatusReport() As List(Of Table) 
        Dim statusReport As New List(Of Table)() 

        Dim doc As XElement = XElement.Load("Data/Report.xml") 

        statusReport = (From row In doc.Elements() _ 
            Select GetReport(row)).ToList() 

        Return statusReport 
    End Function 

    Private Function GetReport(ByVal row As XElement) As Table
        Dim s As New Table() 
        s.JobID= row.Attribute("ID").Value 
        s.VenueName= row.Attribute("Name").Value) 
        Return s 
    End Function 
End Class
```

Beyond those fixes, I can't tell you if it is correct or not... Where is it failing?